# Что такое комментарий к тексту?

Tags: стилистика

Помогите, пожалуйста, можете в общих словах сказать мне, что такое комментарий к проблеме? В интернете есть шаблоны как писать комментарий, но все равно не совсем понимаю, что это. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Суть комментария – показать, как автор решает эту проблему:  На какие аспекты проблемы автор обращает особое внимание? В чём своеобразие авторской трактовки? Как автор сумел донести свою мысль до читателя? Что помогло ему в этом? Привести 2 аргумента(примера,эпизода) автора, с помощью которых он доказывает идею.

Клише

•Эту проблему автор раскрывает на примере  …

•Решая проблему, (обосновывая свою точку зрения), автор приводит интересные примеры(аргументы).

• Комментируя проблему, нельзя не отметить мастерство автора в передаче душевного состояния рассказчика.

• Этот вопрос автор раскрывает, изучая…

•  Рассматривая проблему на примере …, автор с сочувствием (тревогой, иронией, возмущением и т.д.) рассказывает о том…

• Автор показывает проблему с двух сторон.

• Комментируя эту проблему, нельзя не отметить ряд её интересных аспектов.

• Он обращает внимание читателя на …

• Писатель, ведя повествование от лица рассказчика (героя, от своего лица), даёт возможность …

• Ни одна деталь не остаётся незамеченной, поэтому…

• Автор так воссоздаёт эту историю, что…

• Каждая реплика героя позволяет понять, что…

• Автор за частными судьбами видит решение общей проблемы (судьбу страны, судьбу человечества, решение нравственных проблем нашего времени), поэтому на протяжение всего текста звучит мысль о …

• Подтекст позволяет увидеть

Comment: Людмила, Спасибо большое за ответ! А вот если автор пишет свою работу от первого лица, значит ли это, что он рассказывает про себя? Можно ли тогда в комментарии написать: автор на своём примере показывает...?

Comment: От первого лица может идти повествование от лица рассказчика. Это не обязательно автор. Лучше сказать герой-рассказчик. Смотря какой текст.